# how to mock a method decorated with Python Flask route()

Tags: flask, mocking, python-unittest

I need to unit test whether a method decorated by a Flask `route()` gets called or not.

I'd like to do this *without* modifying the original code under test, if possible, so mocking the method would suite my requirements perfectly.

Hence I am asking this *specific* question about how to mock a decorated request method (I want to stress this to try to avoid people wasting their time with less specific answers)...

Sample application `jflask.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

@app.route('/hello')           # This method represents the code under test.
def hello():                   # I want to assert that this method gets
    return 'Hello, World'      # called without modifying this code.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

In the unit test I'm using `@patch()` to mock the method so I can assert it was called, but the assertion fails. I.e. the mock method doesn't get called, when I expect it to.

Sample unit test `test_hello.py`:

```
import unittest
import jflask
from unittest.mock import patch

class jTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        #jflask.app.testing = True
        self.app = jflask.app.test_client()

    @patch('jflask.hello')                # mock the hello() method
    def test_hello(self, mock_method):
        rv = self.app.get('/hello')
        mock_method.assert_called()    # this assertion fails
```

What am I doing wrong ?

---

*Background*

Some background information about the *actual* behaviour I'm trying to test
(since the above is just a condensed test case, and may not seem entirely sane by itself).

In the actual code I am unit testing, there is a `before_request()` handler
installed for the app. This gets called by Flask before each request is handled, and in
certain situations this handler has been designed to return a response value, which
causes Flask request processing to stop (in this application's case, this feature is used to centrally validate request parameters), so that the usual routed request handler will (deliberately) not get called.

My unit tests need to assert that request processing gets stopped
or continues, appropriately depending on the situation.
Hence, my test needs to mock the real request handler and assert whether
it was called or not.

Comment: Think about *when* the mock gets applied - you've already executed the definitions in the code under test, Flask has registered *the original `hello`*. This seems pretty close to testing the framework rather than your code and is definitely testing implementation rather than behaviour; maybe test that you get the right *response*, irrespective of which specific method is called.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, the code above is just a reduced test case - I realise it doesn't make much sense by itself. In the actual code, I am forced to mock the method, so testing the response is not an option. FYI there is a `before_request()` handler installed in the app which affects whether the actual request method will be called or not - and it's this behaviour that I need to test.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to talk about the *actual behaviour you're trying to test*, then? Otherwise you risk getting a solution to an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @jonrsharpe, if Flask has already registered the original `hello()`, is there any way to mock it afterwards - or do I need to mock it in the test setup ?

Comment: You mean replace the version Flask's registered with a mock? Probably, but I don't know enough about the implementation of Flask to tell you how (and the fact that you *need* to know about Flask's implementation suggests that it isn't going to be a useful test).

Comment: @jonrsharpe, You are right about the XY problem. I've added some background to the question, to try to reduce the risk. Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you continue to test at the request-response integration level without mocking? If your central handling is for request validation, presumably it responds to the client with a 4xx error code and doesn't have any side effects - you can test for the response directly, then make a GET to check that the data hasn't changed. Then if you make a valid request you should see a 2xx response and a side effect. This is the *behaviour* you want, and doesn't worry about the specific implementation of e.g. request validation - if you refactor it into that one method later your tests still pass.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, the code under test is actually part of a RESTful API server. The methods under test do much more than just "hello world"; they call other APIs and rely on other system components which I would have to mock. For this particular test, it would be much easier for me if I could just mock the request handler.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hacky but you could inject a logger.

```
@app.route(...):
def hello(logger=None):
  logger = logger or self.logger
  logger.info(...)
  return ...

def test_...(self):
  logger = MagicMock()
  self.app.get(logger)
  self.assertTrue(logger.info.called)
```

Comment: I want to avoid modifying the code under test (the `hello()` method) if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import wraps
import logging
from datetime import datetime
logging.basicConfig(filename=datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y.log'),level=logging.INFO)

def logger_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        logging.info(f.__name__  + ' was called')   
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated 

@app.route('/hello')
@logger_required
def hello():                   # I want to assert that this gets called
    return 'Hello, World'
```

Comment: This will create a text file in current directory & has below log                              
INFO:root:hello was called

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clear that I want to do this without modifying the system (code) under test. This is why my specific question is how to mock a method decorated with Python Flask route().